# Why does MassTransit not push messages to MSMQ unless a subscriber is present? How is this worked-around?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit + MSMQ as a message passing bus, which seems to be having reasonable success.  However, for some tests I want to enqueue messages but never dequeue them.  It seems like the right way to do this is to not subscribe to the queue directly.  Here is my code:

1) I want to send and receive messages from the same queue in this process [this works]:

```
    var solrMessageBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/my_queue");
            sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
            {
                subs.Handler<MyMessage>(msg => Enqueue(msg));
            });
        });
```

2) I want to send messages from this process, but not consume them.  MSMQ should build up a large queue of messages [this *does not work*]

```
    var solrMessageBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/my_queue");
        });
```

I'm not a MassTransit expert, but the above seems like a reasonable way to enqueue without dequeuing messages from that same queue.  In 1), I see messages end up in my MSMQ, but in 2) no messages ever get to the queue.

How can I build up the queue without dequeuing the messages?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not register any subscriptions on the bus, the queue will be emptied and all of the message sent to the queue will end up in the _error queue.

If you need to just send messages to a queue, you can use an EndpointCacheFactory (instead of a service bus factory) to get an IEndpointCache, then call GetEndpoint(uri) and use the Send method to send messages to that queue. This has the added benefit of avoiding any thread pool usage for receiving messages that are never consumed.

*Also, a quick reminder, every service bus instance must have its own queue.*

Answer (score 0):

That sounds reasonable however I've never tried it.

Mass Transit builds the subscription mapping out of your setup and then maps subscriptions to queues (using multicast subscription). Note that messages are **never** stored in queues assigned to senders, rather they are multicasted to subscribers. No subscribers = nowhere to put your messages.

To queue messages forever, I would add a subscriber but pause its consumer thread until tests are completed.

Comment: This is more or less down the right path. You can use static routing and not have your consumer running to help as well. The MT mailing list would likely be a better place to discuss in more detail.